# How do I fix an error starting QGIS 1.8.0 on Windows XP?

Tags: qgis, windows, error

I note that the installation of qgis completed successfully. However, the log procedure returns this message:

> "...... Estrazione: wvhpgn.gsb Estrazione: wyhpgn.gsb Cartella di
>   destinazione: C:\Programmi\Quantum GIS Lisboa Creato il programma di
>   disinstallazione: C:\Programmi\Quantum GIS Lisboa\Uninstall-QGIS.exe
>   Crea cartella: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu
>   Avvio\Programmi\Quantum GIS Lisboa
>   **Impossibile accedere al file. Il file Š utilizzato da un altro processo.** Running postinstall grass64.bat... Running postinstall
>   msvcrt.bat... ......"
>
> System parameters: Quantum GIS Lisboa 1.8.0  Microsoft Windows
>   Professional, Versione 2002, Service Pack 3

The message:

> Impossibile accedere al file. Il file Š utilizzato da un altro
>   processo

translates as

> Unable to access the file. The file used by another process

I then get the following error:

> "Impossibile trovare il punto di ingresso locale_charset della
>   procedura nella libreria di collegamento dinamico iconv.dll"

which translates as:

> Can not find the entry point of locale_charset procedure in the
>   dynamic link library iconv.dll

Answer (score 1):

Renaming 'iconv.dll' in the c:\windows directory worked for me.
(by renaming, not deleting you can restore it if required)

I have 8 of these files in various directories on my computer however the fast indexed 'windows desktop search' only found 2 of them. Using the old windows 'search companion' is a better (but longer) search.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing QGIS in a folder without blanks, e.g. `C:\QuantumGisLisboa\`.

The standalone installer has a few bugs relating to blanks in pathnames.